# java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.transactionManager

Tags: grails

I was trying to do `run-app` in my grails application but it gives the following Java access error .. any solution? I tried to fix it myself but was not able to. 
  Has anyone faced the same problem. I don't have any more description.

```
2014-05-06 09:14:07,119 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.transactionManager from class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormStaticApi.<init>(HibernateGormStaticApi.groovy:83)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateGormEnhancer.getStaticApi(HibernateGormEnhancer.groovy:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer.enhance(GormEnhancer.groovy:103)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEnhancer$enhance.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils$_enhanceSessionFactory_closure3.doCall(HibernateUtils.groovy:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:272)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.call(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils.enhanceSessionFactory(HibernateUtils.groovy:146)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils$enhanceSessionFactory.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils.enhanceSessionFactories(HibernateUtils.groovy:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils.enhanceSessionFactories(HibernateUtils.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.HibernateUtils$enhanceSessionFactories.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
    at grails.plugin.hibernate3.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure3.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:451)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1259)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1085)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:909)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at grails.plugin.hibernate3.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure3.call(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithDynamicMethods(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:702)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPluginManager.doDynamicMethods(DefaultGrailsPluginManager.java:785)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:173)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:122)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
```

Comment: Can you check your datasource configurations if they are correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to indicate a conflicting version of the grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate and grails-datastore-gorm jars.

Run ‘grails dependency-report’ and check you are running the same version for both these jars, and if you are not correct your dependency graph.

Comment: yes you a right. I did solve this problem yesterday. i was using hibernate 3.6.10.2 with grails 2.3.0  it works fine when i changed the hibernate version to 3.6.10.1.